# ASP .NET - Use asp:CheckBox in ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a .NET 3.5 ListView control and would like to display a TINYINT field value as a checkbox (0 = False, 1 = True).

How to do this?

I was trying:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="freight_foundCheckbox" runat="server" 
Checked='<%# Eval("found") %>'  />
```

But this results in a Cast error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="freight_foundCheckbox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("found")) %>'  />
```

Answer (score 3):

That won't work on an int field.  You have to make sure the property you're binding to is a Boolean/bool.

Answer (score 1):

The example above will throw an exception. You need to convert the value to bool:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="freight_foundCheckbox" runat="server" Checked='<%# (int)Eval("found") == 1 ? true : false  %>' />
```